# ld: library not found for -lBoringSSL-GRPC clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I am currently having issues archiving my react native project in Xcode. Building and running my project works fine in Debug but archiving is a problem. The following error appears when attempting to archive:

ld: library not found for lBoringSSL-GRPC
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I have tried removing 'Firebase/Firestore' from my Podfile, running pod install and then trying to archive but that doesn't seem to help. I would get the error:

ld: library not found for lDoubleConversion
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

[image]

I have tried removing the quotes from the library search paths in the build settings as suggested from someone who had a similar issue. This didn't help unfortunately.

[image]

I am opening the workspace. Although, when opening .workspace it does direct me to my project .xcodeproj. Not sure if this is the problem.

Can someone please assist? I would really appreciate it. I'm clueless here. I'm fairly new to Xcode and React Native.

Thank you.